# Задача Делёж яблок

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Делёж яблок — 2

`n` школьников делят `k` яблок “почти поровну”, то есть так, чтобы количество яблок, доставшихся любым двум школьникам, отличалось бы не более, чем на 1.

Программа получает на вход натуральное число `n` и целое неотрицательное число `k`, каждое в отдельной строке, и должна вывести количество школьников, которым достанется яблок меньше, чем некоторым из их товарищей.

| Ввод | Вывод |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 5 |
| 30 |  |

| Ввод | Вывод |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 0 |
| 28 |  |

Comment: Ваш вопрос был заминусован и возможно скоро будет закрыт. Чтобы избежать этого добавьте ваши собственные попытки решения в вопрос и ознакомьтесь с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Можно взять остаток от деления `k` на `n` — количество человек, которым яблок достанется больше. Вычитая из `n` это число, получаем ответ — количество человек, которым яблок достанется меньше. Не забываем про крайний случай.

***Пример:***

```py
n, k = map(int, input().split())

if k % n:
    print(n - k % n)
else:
    print(0)
```

Comment: Не надо отвечать на такие вопросы.

Comment: `print(-k % n)`.